# Unexpected behaviour of 'order by' clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by

I have a table which looks like

```
Col1    col2 col3 col4 col5
1  5       1     4     6
1  4       0     3     7
0  1       5     6     3
1  8       2     1     5
4  3       2     1     4
```

The script is

```
declare @t table(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int,col4 int,col5 int)
insert into @t
select 1,5,1,4,6 union all
select 1,4,0,3,7 union all
select 0,1,5,6,3 union all
select 1,8,2,1,5 union all
select 4,3,2,1,4
```

I want the output to be every column being sorted in ascending order, i.e.,

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
    0  1       0     1     3
    1  3       1     1     4
    1  4       2     3     5
    1  5       2     4     6
    4  8       5     6     7
```

How can I do it?

Comment: can you explain why you want that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns are not independent of their row -- sort order applies to the whole row, not to individual columns.  All data within a row is understood to be related -- you cannot individually slice/dice/rearrange data that violates this.

You can't do what you want to do in the current structure you have.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't say it's *impossible* to return those results, but it's almost certainly Doing It Wrong(tm) at one or more levels.

Comment: Sir, then what will be the query for achieving that.. could u please help

Comment: @Newbie: If you can edit your post to describe what you're actually trying to accomplish, maybe we can help you with that instead. Taking a *wild* guess, it seems that your table isn't normalized properly.

Comment: The reason nobody is willing to give you an answer is that (a) as Jon Seigel said, it would be super-hard to do; and (b) the fact that you're breaking apart values that are in the same record and re-associating them with values from different records strongly suggests that there's something wrong in the way you've constructed your data model. If you're willing to give a more concrete explanation of what you're trying to do, perhaps we could come up with a model that would work better.

Comment: @Newbie, example of a table with columns named `FirstName`, `LastName` and `City`. It makes no sense to sort the columns independently, since first and last name and city must stay together.

Answer (score 4):

That sort order is correct.

It's sorted first by col1, and then by col2 (within any duplicates in col1), etc...

Notice how for the same value in col2, col2 is in ascending order:

```
Col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1       4         0     3       7
1       5         1     4       6
1       8         2     1       5
```

Here's another example. Imagine we have a list of `Lastname, Firstname`:

```
Smith, Ian
Smith, John
Smith, Dave
Smith, Jane
Green, Jim
```

Sorted by `Lastname ASC, Firstname ASC`, that would be:

```
Green, Jim
Smith, Dave
Smith, Ian
Smith, Jane
Smith, John
```

Comment: But I want the output to be sorted for every column

Comment: The thing you think you want is impossible!! You would have to treat each column as separate from its row.

Comment: @Newbie, I think you are using the table like an Excel sheet. A database table is quite different. Maybe should have only two columns in this table. One attribute telling you which "column" is meant and one value column. So, basically each value would be in its own record. Then you can create the desired output with an appropriate query.